# Quickly find the information on the GridView?

Tags: c#-2.0

See attached image file: [image]

Assuming the data is loaded from SQL Server, GridView includes 5 columns as shown above, cells Search of textbox where you find out quickly (due to its use on the image for illustration), in his cell this search textbox enter any value in the column that has (according to this column 5), the GridView grid lines present value of the lookup value, usually looking to have a value equal to 1 column with which to look.

If you use fast search method does not need to specify one column before it, how to write this quickly find how to load into the GridView ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but if your looking for a fast way to search the contents of a datagridview you can bind the SQL result to a bindingsource, use the bindingsource as the datagridviews data source and then set the binding sources filter to "dataproperty LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';"

Refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx

Sorry if this isn't what you're asking for!